# Httpie can not decode my Bottle API Gzipped respond

Tags: python, http, encoding, zlib, bottle

I have a HTTP/JSON Restful server implemented in Python thanks to the Bottle Web framework. I want to Gzip the data sent to the client.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
# curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"key1": 1, "key2": 2}' http://localhost:6789/post
#

from bottle import run, request, post, route, response
from zlib import compress
import json

data = {'my': 'json'}


@post('/post')
def api_post():
    global data
    data = json.loads(request.body.read())
    return(data)


@route('/get')
def api_get():
    global data
    response.headers['Content-Encoding'] = 'identity'
    return(json.dumps(data).encode('utf-8'))


@route('/getgzip')
def api_get_gzip():
    global data
    if 'gzip' in request.headers.get('Accept-Encoding', ''):
        response.headers['Content-Encoding'] = 'gzip'
        ret = compress(json.dumps(data).encode('utf-8'))
    else:
        response.headers['Content-Encoding'] = 'identity'
        ret = json.dumps(data).encode('utf-8')
    return(ret)


run(host='localhost', port=6789, debug=True)
```

When i test my server with Curl, the result is good (if i use the --compressed option tag):

```
$ curl  -H "Accept-encoding: gzip, deflated" -v --compressed http://localhost:6789/getgzip
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 6789 (#0)
> GET /getgzip HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:6789
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> Accept-encoding: gzip, deflated
> 
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 200 OK
< Date: Sun, 12 Nov 2017 09:09:09 GMT
< Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.12
< Content-Length: 22
< Content-Encoding: gzip
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< 
* Closing connection 0
{"my": "json"}
```

But not with HTTPie (or Firefox, or Chrome...):

```
$ http http://localhost:6789/getgzipHTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 22
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Sun, 12 Nov 2017 09:10:10 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.12

http: error: ContentDecodingError: ('Received response with content-encoding: gzip, but failed to decode it.', error('Error -3 while decompressing: incorrect header check',))
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

I Nicolargo,

According to the documentation of Httpie, default encoding is set to `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate` but your are using the `compress` Python function of the `zlib` module which implement a [Lempel–Ziv–Welch Compression Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Welch) (Gzip is based on [DEFLATE Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFLATE)).

Or, according to the documentation of Bottle (https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/recipes.html#gzip-compression-in-bottle) you will need a custom middleware to perform a gzip compression (see an example there: http://svn.cherrypy.org/tags/cherrypy-2.1.1/cherrypy/lib/filter/gzipfilter.py).

**Edit:**

The `compress` function of the `zlib` module do perform a gzip compatible compression.

I think it's more related to the the `header` of the data (as the Error mention). In http://svn.cherrypy.org/tags/cherrypy-2.1.1/cherrypy/lib/filter/gzipfilter.py there is a use of a `write_gzip_header` maybe you can try this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the edit section of Guillaume, it's now work with both Httpie and Curl.

Here is the complete code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
# curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"key1": 1, "key2": 2}' http://localhost:6789/post
#

from bottle import run, request, post, route, response
import zlib
import json
import struct
import time

data = {'my': 'json'}


@post('/post')
def api_post():
    global data
    data = json.loads(request.body.read())
    return(data)


@route('/get')
def api_get():
    global data
    response.headers['Content-Encoding'] = 'identity'
    return(json.dumps(data).encode('utf-8'))


@route('/getgzip')
def api_get_gzip():
    global data
    ret = json.dumps(data).encode('utf-8')
    if 'gzip' in request.headers.get('Accept-Encoding', ''):
        response.headers['Content-Encoding'] = 'gzip'
        ret = gzip_body(ret)
    else:
        response.headers['Content-Encoding'] = 'identity'
    return(ret)


def write_gzip_header():
    header = '\037\213'      # magic header
    header += '\010'         # compression method
    header += '\0'
    header += struct.pack("<L", long(time.time()))
    header += '\002'
    header += '\377'
    return header


def write_gzip_trailer(crc, size):
    footer = struct.pack("<l", crc)
    footer += struct.pack("<L", size & 0xFFFFFFFFL)
    return footer


def gzip_body(body, compress_level=6):
    yield gzip_header()
    crc = zlib.crc32("")
    size = 0
    zobj = zlib.compressobj(compress_level,
                            zlib.DEFLATED, -zlib.MAX_WBITS,
                            zlib.DEF_MEM_LEVEL, 0)
    size += len(data)
    crc = zlib.crc32(data, crc)
    yield zobj.compress(data)
    yield zobj.flush()
    yield gzip_trailer(crc, size)


run(host='localhost', port=6789, debug=True)
```

It's a little complicated but it do the job...